# Can not show labels in group bar chart d3js v6

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to follow as following link to put labels in the groups bar chart, but it does not show up.

Anyone know what's going on my text label?

http://plnkr.co/edit/9lAiAXwet1bCOYL58lWN?p=preview&preview

[Append text to Grouped Bar Chart in d3js v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870977/append-text-to-grouped-bar-chart-in-d3js-v4)

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph

```
var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 },
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const dataUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yushinglui/IV/main/time_distance_status_v2.csv"

//fetch the data
d3.csv(dataUrl)
    .then((data) => {

        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        var svg = d3.select("#graph-2")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")



        // List of subgroups = header of the csv files = soil condition here
        var subgroups = data.columns.slice(1)

        // List of groups = species here = value of the first column called group -> I show them on the X axis
        var groups = d3.map(data, function (d) { return (d.startTime) })

        // Add X axis
        var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(groups)
            .range([0, width])
            .padding([0.2])
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

        // Add Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 20])
            .range([height, 0]);
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        // Another scale for subgroup position?
        var xSubgroup = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(subgroups)
            .range([0, x.bandwidth()])
            .padding([0.05])

        // color palette = one color per subgroup
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(subgroups)
            .range(['#98abc5', '#8a89a6'])



        // Show the bars
        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            // Enter in data = loop group per group
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.startTime) + ",0)"; })
        
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) { return subgroups.map(function (key) { return { key: key, value: d[key] }; }); })
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return xSubgroup(d.key); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("width", xSubgroup.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.key); })
  
         



        //axis labels
        svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', - (height / 2))
            .attr('y', width - 650)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style("font-size", "17px")
            .text('Average Distance');

        svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', 300)
            .attr('y', width - 240)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate()')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style("font-size", "17px")
            .text('Start Time');

        // legend
        svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 200).attr("cy", 20).attr("r", 6).style("fill", "#98abc5")
        svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 300).attr("cy", 20).attr("r", 6).style("fill", "#8a89a6")
        svg.append("text").attr("x", 220).attr("y", 20).text("Present").style("font-size", "15px").attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        svg.append("text").attr("x", 320).attr("y", 20).text("Absent").style("font-size", "15px").attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")

       //text labels on bars
        
       svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            // Enter in data = loop group per group
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.startTime) + ",0)"; })
        
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(function (d) {
                return [d['P'], d['ABS']];
            })
            .enter()
            .append("text")  
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .text(function (d) {
                return formatCount(d)
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                var x0 = xSubgroup.bandwidth() * i + 11,
                    y0 = y(d) + 8;
                return "translate(" + x0 + "," + y0 + ") rotate(90)";
            })


    });
```

Comment: can you provide code snippet?

Comment: try to console here..........    .text(function (d) { console.log(formatCount(d)
                return formatCount(d)
            })

Comment: try it but it is not work

Comment: Your Plunker displays labels on each bar. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
      try this...and if possible please provide code snippet....
     

        svg.append("text")  
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .text(function (d) {
            console.log( formatCount(d) )
            return formatCount(d)
        })
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            var x0 = xSubgroup.bandwidth() * i + 11,
                y0 = y(d) + 8;
            return "translate(" + x0 + "," + y0 + ") rotate(90)";
        })
```